# Selecting a random user from my Firebase user list

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm working on an application that has a reward system based around a random Firebase user receiving a reward on a certain event.

I got everything else down, but I have no idea about how to select my random user from Firebase. Does anyone know how I can go about getting a random user ID form my list of user?

Comment: `list.get(new Random().nextInt(list.size()))`?

Comment: also depends what variable type `user ID` is

Comment: Firebase Authentication doesn't expose a public API to get a user list. Please expand your question to include more details on how you expect to use this feature.

Comment: so i want a method or command that will allow me to pick a random user from the list of authenticated users. once i have this random user i want to send them a in app message to inform them of their recent luck.

Answer (score 0):

use this sir. just input the range and minimum

```
(Math.random() * "range") + "min";
```

Comment: int randomNumber = (Math.random() * list.size()) + 1; in this case the range of random number is based on list.size and the minimum is 1. I'm assuming your id is from 1 to size of list.

Comment: in case you have error trying my first comment...int randomNumber = (int) ((Math.random() * list.size()) + 1);  then get the record using the "randomNumber"

Answer (score 0):

Creating a function to get a random Firebase user in Swift

Class

```
import FirebaseDatabase

var ref: DatabaseReference!
```

ViewDidLoad

```
ref = Database.database().reference()

chooseRandomUser()
```

Func

```
func chooseRandomUser()
{
let profilesRef = ref.child("users")

profilesRef.observe(.value, with:
    {
      snapshot in

      let allProfiles = snapshot.children.shuffled()
      let randomProfile = allProfiles.randomElement()
      let winner = randomProfile!

      print(winner)
     })
}
```